# Why is Mocha not running on travis

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, travis-ci

My mocha tests run fine locally. But on travis no tests are run, all I see is "0 passing".

I have a simple `.travis.yml`

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.10"
```

and the `scripts` section of my package.json is configured like this

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha"
}
```

If you need more info on the project you can check https://github.com/theblacksmith/typescript-compiler

Here is the travis page for the project: https://travis-ci.org/theblacksmith/typescript-compiler

Comment: SO editorial practices **require** that you put the code that is relevant to your question inside the body of the question itself. Links to provide **additional** information are allowed, provided that they do **not** replace the code that is relevant to your question. If you have too much code, this is a sign that you should create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Louis As far as I know, the relevant code is there. That's the configuration required by Travis to run my tests. I actually found the problem it was a "structural" problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of building your `.ts` files to `.js` you could specify [mocha `--compilers` option](http://mochajs.org/#compilers-option). To do so you should first add [`typescript-require` module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/typescript-require) to your `devDependencies`:

```
npm install typescript-require --save-dev
```

Then you'll be able to use it as `.ts` compiler:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers ts:typescript-require"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using TypeScript and didn't setup the build process to compile the tests to js before running mocha. So if you are using any transpiler, make sure you configure the build to convert them to js. Here's the final configuration code

**.travis.yml**

```
language: node_js

node_js:
  - "0.10"

before_script:
  - make build
```

**Makefile**

```
build:
    @echo "  Building..."
    @cp src/typescript/bin/lib.* lib/
    @node ./src/typescript/bin/tsc.js -m commonjs -t ES5 src/index.ts --out index.js
    @echo "  Done!"

.PHONY: build
```

**package.json** (scripts session)

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "make build",
  "test": "node ./src/typescript/bin/tsc.js -m commonjs -t ES5 test/*.ts && ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha"
}
```